# Need to fetch two specific field values from one model to another seperately in django API rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-viewsets

**model 1**

```
class Users(models.Model):

    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    pancard=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    aadhar=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    personal_email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    emergency_contact_no=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    emergency_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    relation=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    blood_group=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES,null=True)  
    desingnation=models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="desingnation")
    billable_and_non_billable=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES,default='Billable')
    joining_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    relieving_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name
```

**model 2**

```
class Consolidated(models.Model):
    
    emp_name=models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE)
    proj_name=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE)
    custom_name=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE)
    Cons_date=models.ForeignKey(Add_Timelog,on_delete=CASCADE)
    bill_no_bill=models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="billable_and_non_billable+")
    
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.emp_name)
```

**Serializers**

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
        model= Users
        fields = '__all__'

class Consolidated_serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=Consolidated
        fields= '__all__'
```

**Viewsets**

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    queryset=models.Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.UserSerializers

class Consolidated_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    queryset=models.Consolidated.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.Consolidated_serializers
```

Actually I was stucked in the middle, as I need to take the values from '`billable_and_non_billable`' field from the `Users` model and display those values under `Consolidated` model `bill_no_bill` field. With the above code I can only take the `employee_name` values from the `Users` model to the `emp_name` of `Consolidated` model and the same value is getting displayed in the `bill_no_bill` field. Please help me find any ways for this problem as I am new to this Django. Basically its needs to be a API which operates GET method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting same value because you are using Foreign Key to the user model for both `emp_name` and `bill_no_bill`. Foreign keys are used for many to one relations between models.
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

So your Consolidated Model should be:

```
class Consolidated(models.Model):
    employee=models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE)
    custom_name=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE)
    cons_date=models.ForeignKey(Add_Timelog,on_delete=CASCADE)
```

To get the values of these fields you can use [Nested Objects Representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) in DRF serializers.

So the consolidated serializer becomes:

```
class ConsolidatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Consolidated
        fields = ['employee', 'project', 'custom', 'date']
```

The `bill_no_bill` field would be part of the returned object in viewset.

Alternatively you can override the to_representation method of serializer or [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: Can you please help me to set a serializers for the above code. I Cant able to do that with the one you mentioned.

Comment: @vinothkumar I have edited my answer and tried to implement the serializer to the best of my understanding. You should read up on the links attached in the answer for better understanding on how to redactor your project.

Comment: Thanks, one doubt on the employee = UserSerializer() can I add only the fields I need from the User model(like employee_name and billable_and_non_billable) field in the place of user serializer declared